# how to interwoven the given string using function

Tags: javascript

I am very new to javascript programming and I have one puzzle as mention below.

How function to take in a string and return a string that is itself with the reverse of it interwoven together. For example, "ab12" would be"ab12" and "21ba" interwoven to make: "a2b11b2a"

I trying this way which give error.any help will appreciate.
Thanks

```
function interwoven(str) {
var newString = "";
for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (var j = str.length; i <= 0; i++)
    newString += str[j+i];
 }
return newString;
}
interwoven('ab12');
```

Comment: `"ab12".replace(/(?=)/g, (_,index,str) => str.charAt(str.length-index))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two indices `i` that increments and `j` that decrements.

```js
function interwoven(str) {
  var i = 0, len = str.length, j = len - 1, newString = "";
  for (; i < len; i++, j--) {
    newString += str[i] + str[j]
  }
  return newString;
}
console.log(interwoven('ab12'));
```

Comment: Thanks@Yury its awesome. you make my life easy

Comment: @Abhirock Glad I could help.

Comment: sorry to ask one query Is it my question is wrong or inappropriate as its given -1?

Comment: @Abhirock Who knows :) Mb the downvoter assumes you haven't done your research or whatever.

Comment: Ok Thanks I will take care about it:-)

Answer (score 0):

I would just do this:

```js
    function interwoven(str) {
        return str.split('').reduce((acc, cur, idx, src) => 
            acc + cur + src[src.length - (idx + 1)], '');
    }

    console.log(interwoven('ab12'))
```

Comment: Thanks@Dave it really helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
    function interwoven(string) {
    // store string in array string-array
    let string-array = string.split('');
    // copy string-array, reverse, and store in string-array-reverse
    let string-array-reverse = string-array.reverse();
    let interwoven-array = [];
    let index;
    for (index = 0; index < string-array.length; index++) {
        interwoven-array.push(string-array[index]);
        interwoven-array.push(string-array-reverse[index]);
    }

    return interwoven-array;
}

interwoven('ab12');
```

Comment: Thanks@rpivovar it really helpful